# How to interpret klocwork architect reports?

Tags: architecture, report, klocwork

I have generated a KlocWork Architect PDF report which gives a graphical representation of the java module / file relationship.
But the graphical report contains numbers over the arrows.
What I would like to know is how to interpret these numbers?
Does the Arrow denote “Directed dependency between designated blocks”?
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Also, does the report give what all method/global variables are modified, and what all functions are affected with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in Klocwork Support, and I answered a [similar question](http://developer.klocwork.com/community/forums/klocwork-insight/user-tools/how-interpret-klocwork-architect-generated-pdf-reports) on the Klocwork support forums as well, which may have also been from you.

What the arrows denote really depends on the diagram or model you were viewing when you created the report, and the [relationship types](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/Insight-9.6/Supported_relationship_types) displayed at the time.  The [report summary section](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/Insight-9.6/Creating_an_architecture_report_with_Klocwork_Architect#Structure_of_the_architecture_report) should explain which relationship types the report contains.  By default Klocwork Architect always shows all relationships unless you've changed or customized the [relationship profile](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/Insight-9.6/Working_with_Architect_models_and_custom_diagrams#Managing_how_you_view_relationships) you are using.  The number beside the arrow is the number of relationships between the components, of the relationship types that are enabled.

Depending on the entities and relationships being shown, Klocwork Architect can show whether variables or class members are read or written to. For the complete details please review the [Supported Relationship types](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/Insight-9.6/Supported_relationship_types) mentioned above, and the [Supported Entity types](http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/Insight-9.6/Supported_entity_types).